# Unnecessary includes in c++

Tags: c++, include, header-files

My question is about includes in c++. Imagine these 3 .h files

```
// A.h
#include "B.h"
class A {
    B b;
}
```

```
// B.h
#include "C.h"
class B {
    C c;
}
```

```
// C.h
class C {

}
```

The problem here is, that A.h needs access to B.h, but not C.h.

A.h can in this situation access C.h through B.h, so it's an unnecessary include. Lately I've been in this situation much, so I'm wondering how this situation can be avoided.

Comment: Yes, A.h needs C.h, because it uses B, which uses C. What are you asking about?

Comment: 'A' never instantiates a variable of type 'C', but it still needs the include because 'B' uses it?

Comment: Use *include guards* so the order is not significant.

Comment: There's a `C` inside the `B`, so instantiating `B` also instantiates `C`. You need the include.

Comment: I've seen 'include guards' before, but I've never understood what they actually do. Can you link a good source to learn about them?

Comment: Ok, I understand. it's not an unnecessary include then. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DeadlyCow They have little to do with this question. And the order IS significant here.

Comment: @DeadlyCow "_'A' never instantiates a variable of type 'C'_" It **does** instantiate C, by the act of instantiating `B`.

Comment: @Barmer What do you mean with 'the order IS significant'? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Example of unnecessary include would be `#include C.h` in `A.h`.

Comment: The rule of thumb is:  include what you use.  A depends on B, so A should include B.  B depends on C, so B should include C.  Also use header guards, or `#pragma once`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem here is, that A.h needs access to B.h, but not C.h.

There are no unnecessary includes in your code. `A.h` does not need to include `C.h` directly but `A.h` cannot use `B.h` without (indirectly) also including `C.h`

Answer (score 1):

First of all; in many situations you don't need the full definition of a type (when just using a pointer or reference to it or when using it as a return value). In these cases you can use forward declarations instead of including the full header.
Secondly; if your headers have proper include guards, then including them multiple times costs very little.

I know of no *good* tools to find unneeded includes (the google "include what you use" tool tried, but doesn't really work well in my experience). You'll just have to use your knowledge of the code to identify unneeded includes and remove them by hand, I'm afraid.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about including the file multiple times.

Comment: @Barmar No, there is not. I expanded a bit - so, shoot me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done. In c++, the preprocessor, which includes the `#include` directives, returns a text file that the actual compiler then processes. This is currently the only way to get code into your project. If `B.h` needs `C.h`, it will have to be there in text form before `A.h`.

The c++ compiler has no way of "forgetting" previously required definitions within one translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

Use include guards as suggested above.

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_
#include B.h
class A {
    B b;
}
#endif
```

Also you could use pointers to classes and then construct and delete the classes explicitly. An include file without inline code that references the class members and methods only needs to know that the things it contains are classes to have a member that is a pointer to that class. I think this may be a form of encapsulation but I cannot find a good example.

```
class B;
class A {
    B * b;
}
```

Comment: Aren't 'include guards' the same as '#pragma once'?

Comment: @DeadlyCow • they serve the same purpose.  `#pragma once` is an extension (implemented by most C++ vendors), and not part of the standard.